# convert content of the characteristic in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a question about how I could do this instruction in swift?

```
NSData * data = characteristic.value;
Byte *resultByte = (Byte *)[data bytes];
```

I understand that the first line is like this, but how can I get the bytes

```
let data = characteristic.value! as NSData
```

Comment: Note that `Data` already conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` so there is no need to convert from data to array of bytes `[UInt8]`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of bytes from the data simply with

```
if let data = characteristic.value {
    let bytes = Array(data) // [UInt8]
}
```

But often you don't need to create an extra array because `Data`
is a collection and you can directly access the individual bytes via
subscripting:

```
if let data = characteristic.value {
    let byte0 = data[0]
    let byte1 = data[1]
    // ...
}
```

or get a pointer to the raw bytes with

```
if let data = characteristic.value {
    data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytePtr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
        // ...
    }
}
```